# A popover in NavigationLink does not work properly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When you tap Button2 below, the popover closes immediately for the first time only.

Here is the reproducible code.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink("Button1", destination: ChildView())
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
    
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Button2") {
            isPresented = true
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            Text("Sheet")
        }
    }
}
```

- Xcode12.4
- iPad Pro 11inch / iOS14.0

Screen Capture Video

- https://gist.github.com/shtnkgm/d8ba240f588d3e73ea13c1ff2e6cb1b5#gistcomment-3640543

Comment: the modal screen closes immediately for the first time only, can you be more clear?

Comment: Provided code works fine with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4. Maybe the is in other code? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: This problem is reproduced in the following environment.
 - iPad Pro 11inch（Physical device）/ iOS14.0